# Gulp copy source failing because of .framework folder

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, macos, gulp

I'm trying to run a command that copies my project content into another folder and I keep having this error:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

I narrowed it to know that is the .framework folder that is causing the problem. If I delete it It works ok. The problem is that I need that folder in the project because I'm making an InDesign HTML plugin a PluPlug framework is needed.

This is my env:

```
Mac OSX 10.11.6
npm -v 4.0.5
node -v 7.4.0
gulp -v CLI version 1.2.2Local version 3.9.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the files or folders in gulp try

```
gulp.src(['directory/**', '!**/.framework', '!**/.framework/**'], { dot: true })
```

for more details check this link https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/679

or you can use gulp Copy task
This is just a handy way of copying a files from one folder to another.
There is no goal of replacing other tools out there.
No extra lib or package needed.

```
gulp.task('copy', function () {
    gulp.src('directory/.framework/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('directory/.framework/'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Ignoring those files it works,but I already knew that. I said if I ignore them it works, but I need them in the final package and during development. 
So, I need for gulp to copy them. If not I'll have to make an InDesign package all the time. It's awful unproductive.

Comment: can you post what you have tried as you said you deleted folder not ignored right?

Comment: This are the files I'm copying (all of them but ignoring a few)
This is my gulp "copy" config of files [".debug", "./**/*", "!**/.git", "!**/.git/**", "!**/eclipseWorkspace/**", "!**/node_modules/**", "!**/less/**", "!**/sass/**", "!**/scss/**", "!**/theme/**", "!**/bin/**", "!.gitgnore", "!package.json", "!Gruntfile.js", "!gulpfile.js", "!.log"]

I've done 3 things:

1 - Run normal command => **Error**,
2 - Run ignoring the .framework like you said => **Works**,
3 - Copy only the folder with the .framework => **Error**

Comment: In this case you may like to check and change folder permissions for .framework.

Comment: I was checking my commits list and I found that the framework now contains 2 new things: **A Resources folder with a info.plist inside** and a **Current folder with the same thing**. Deleting this folders seems to fix the copy problem but I'm not sure if i'm not breaking anything else.

Comment: Just an observation, I was checking the latest Plug-Plug Framework and the one I have and I see the difference is that the one is failing has **Alias files** and the one that works fine **don't**